# What is secure way to send request to /oauth/token in Spring Security?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, spring-security-oauth2

What is the ideal/safe way to send a request from client app to get the access token?

I have a REST API (developed using Spring Boot), which is consumed by the client application (developed using React.js) of that API. E.g Stackoverflow has backend API and its frontend client consume that API. The REST API is secured using OAuth2.

The endpoint at which the API returns the access token is

```
http://192.168.43.70:8085/api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=22@gmail.com&password=mypassword
```

along with the client secret. Here is the request from React.js:

```
axios
    .create({
      baseURL:
        "http://192.168.43.70:8085/api/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=22@gmail.com&password=mypassword",
      auth: {
        username: "my-client",
        password: "ZS10ZXN0"
      }
    })
```

Is it the right way, since we are exposing the client secrets (`"my-client"`, `"bGl2ZS10ZXN0"`) to the browser, from where anyone can see the client credentials used for this request?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that this is insecure and not advised. It would be better to use a different grant flow that does not require client credentials.

I'd recommend that you take a look at the `authorization_code` grant flow (without the client secret) instead of the password grant flow. There are a [couple](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/) of [resources](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use) that will give you more background on why to not use the password flow, but briefly from the first:

> Single-page apps (or browser-based apps) run entirely in the browser after loading the Javascript and HTML source code from a web page. Since the entire source is available to the browser, they cannot maintain the confidentiality of a client secret, so the secret is not used for these apps. The *flow is exactly the same as the authorization code flow*, but at the last step, the authorization code is exchanged for an access token without using the client secret.

Even better, though, if you can introduce a server-side component that negotiates with your client via, say, a JSESSIONID (implying changing to a sessioned backend), then I believe you'll find [secrets are much easier to maintain on the backend](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens). You could take a look at [Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 Client support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client) for that.

Comment: But, doesn't JSESSIONID break the `Stateless` constraint of RESTfull architecture? I think it does.

Comment: @TheCoder, yes, that's right. I've clarified in the answer the implication of using the JSESSIONID. I've also added a link that adds some detail to this point.

Answer (score 2):

Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant isn't the right grant type for your application, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3):

> **4.3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**
>
> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application.  The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not viable.

You could use Implicit Grant, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2):

> **4.2. Implicit Grant**
>
> The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens (it does not support the issuance of refresh tokens) and is optimized for public clients known to operate a particular redirection URI.  These clients are typically implemented in a browser using a scripting language such as JavaScript.
>
> [...]
>
> The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and relies on the presence of the resource owner and the registration of the redirection URI. Because the access token is encoded into the redirection URI, it may be exposed to the resource owner and other applications residing on the same device.

but some authorization servers don't support it, because of security issues. Spring Security OAuth2 supports it.

You could also use Authorization Code Grant, although it is optimized for confidential clients, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1):

> **4.1.  Authorization Code Grant**
>
> The authorization code grant type is used to obtain both access tokens and refresh tokens and is optimized for confidential clients.
>
> [...]
>
> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.

but some authorization servers don't support it, because of security issues.  Spring Security OAuth2's default configuration requires client authentication.

Another way would be Authorization Code Grant with PKCE, see [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636):

> **Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients**
>
> Abstract
>
> OAuth 2.0 public clients utilizing the Authorization Code Grant are    susceptible to the authorization code interception attack.  This specification describes the attack as well as a technique to mitigate against the threat through the use of Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE, pronounced "pixy").

but Spring Security doesn't support it, see [4943](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4943).

Comment: Note that the implicit flow is intentionally not implemented by many Authorization Servers--instead, using the Authorization Code flow without the client secret is viewed as a better alternative to implicit: "In practice, there are only very limited cases in which this is necessary. Several major implementations (Keycloak, Deutsche Telekom, Smart Health IT) have chosen to avoid the Implicit Flow completely and use the Authorization Code flow instead." - https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/

Comment: Here's a link that I found helpful about why sites like oauth.com and auth0.com aren't recommending PKCE for SPAs: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182873/why-isnt-pkce-encouraged-for-single-page-apps

Comment: @jzheaux The real problem is that you could find any opinion on the internet. That's the reason I try to stick with the specification (RFC). The spec is not primary opinion based. That is also the reason, I didn't recommend anything.

Comment: @jzheaux See for example that draft [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-parecki-oauth-browser-based-apps-01#section-4).

Comment: @jzheaux I edited my answer to make it more clear, that I don't recommend anything. Also I added some explaination for existing problems with Spring Security OAuth2.

Comment: @jzheaux BTW: Keycloak 4.5 still supports implicit grant.

Comment: Good tips, @dur, especially the link to the draft spec--that one is new for me, I'll make sure to dig in.